# Azure AD B2C error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have been stuck on a problem while implementing Azure AD B2C. I am trying to get a test running for an Android app to see if it will function the way I need it to. I realize there are a lot of other requirements which would be helpful to diagnose this problem, but was hoping somebody had experienced the same problem. I only found [one reference online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55576359/msal-for-android-fails-performing-b2c-login) which did not seem to work. I did get this running once but wanted to recreate it in another tenant and started running into issues again. It looks like a AAD Tenant configuration problem as the code is almost exactly the same and taken from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/azuresamples/msalandroidapp/B2CModeFragment.java). These are in the logcat after I get presented with a login screen and press "Sign In":

```
W/SchemaUtil:  [{"thread_id":"1237","correlation_id":"zzzzzz","x-client-Ver":"2.0.4","x-client-SKU":"MSAL.Android"}] The preferred username is not returned from the IdToken. Android 29
W/SchemaUtil:getAlternativeAccountId:  [{"thread_id":"1237","correlation_id":"zzzzzz","x-client-Ver":"2.0.4","x-client-SKU":"MSAL.Android"}] alternative_account_id was null. Android 29
W/SchemaUtil:getAvatarUrl:  [{"thread_id":"1237","correlation_id":"zzzzzz","x-client-Ver":"2.0.4","x-client-SKU":"MSAL.Android"}] Avatar URL was null. Android 29
D/StartFragment: AuthenticationCallback.onError: com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalClientException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
```

On the AAD side I have a tenant, an application, an Android platform defined in it, and a scope. Based on the errors:

- The preferred username is not returned from the IdToken
- alternative_account_id was null

It would appear that I have an issue with the token being returned. And this one:

- Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference

Might be due to the fact that there is some issue with the token being returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update** Additional information from StackTrace

```
W/System.err: at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.cache.MicrosoftStsAccountCredentialAdapter.getExpiresOn(MicrosoftStsAccountCredentialAdapter.java:289)
W/System.err: at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.cache.MicrosoftStsAccountCredentialAdapter.createAccessToken(MicrosoftStsAccountCredentialAdapter.java:79)
W/System.err: at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.cache.MicrosoftStsAccountCredentialAdapter.createAccessToken(MicrosoftStsAccountCredentialAdapter.java:53)
W/System.err: at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.cache.MsalOAuth2TokenCache.save(MsalOAuth2TokenCache.java:284)
W/System.err: at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.cache.MsalOAuth2TokenCache.saveAndLoadAggregatedAccountData(MsalOAuth2TokenCache.java:443)
W/System.err: at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.BaseController.saveTokens(BaseController.java:532)
W/System.err: at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.LocalMSALController.acquireToken(LocalMSALController.java:177)
W/System.err: at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.commands.InteractiveTokenCommand.execute(InteractiveTokenCommand.java:67)
W/System.err: at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.commands.InteractiveTokenCommand.execute(InteractiveTokenCommand.java:39)
W/System.err: at com.microsoft.identity.common.internal.controllers.CommandDispatcher.executeCommand(CommandDispatcher.java:279)
```

checking into ***getExpiresOn***

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/563#issuecomment-612602011) is where I found the solution. I followed the instructions for creating a scope, adding permissions, and granting admin consent for the tenant and it worked.

I still do not know why all of this is needed or, aside from the post, where it is documented and explained.

I guess I am a little nervous about putting something like this into production.